# How to select an IOS update (cisco)?

Tags: cisco

2) How do you go about selecting the best IOS version to be on after you determine you need to update?

3) If you want to upgrade to a particular version, how do you check whether it's OK to move up to the version you have in mind?

4) Finally - is there a systematic approach to this process, or is it different for each type of hardware / version of IOS you're coming from?  There are numerous Cisco doc's on this, all of them lead down different paths, and none of them have helped me answer these questions plainly. (Or get many any closer to feeling confident about upgrading)

Comment: I would say this has more of a slant toward how to select the image rather than the why of moving to a new image, which is more the point of the linked question.

Comment: Short answer to most of your questions... you need to talk to either Cisco Advanced Services (which is expensive), or hope that your Cisco SE has some inside information on what image would be helpful... however, you should be skeptical of IOS recommendations from sales teams, unless they are backing it up with references from other customers.

Comment: @YLearn thank you for actually taking the time to read the question instead of marking it duplicate without really looking into it. It may be similar in wording to "What factors drive a Cisco IOS upgrade" but the answers over there address only a single facet of my question, and not really along the same vein I asked.

Comment: @all who marked duplicate:  It's not a duplicate question.  Please remove the 'duplicate' tag, so I can get some assistance on this.  The linked question asks 'what factors DRIVE an upgrade', I'm asking a completely different question, as YLearn said the 'how'.

Comment: @user1353, perhaps you should edit your question to remove #1 and references to it in the following.  That would be the one point where your question does overlap with the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

[Cisco Feature Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/) is where you would research when you desire to upgrade your IOS. Generally you upgrade due to bugs or security threats. We read the release notes to see if there are unfixed bugs that will effect our environment and if the code is stable for our environment then we will use it.

Comment: Adam, thanks for this feedback, I've been trying to stick in the Cisco line of tools.  My issue is that frequently it doesn't have record of my images, so I can't see what's missing from a release I'd want to go to.  Also, how do you keep abreast of the release notes, is there a central location?  It seems every mainline release has it's own section on their site you have to navigate to to find this information.